# Past paper stats

Tags: probability, statistics

I am struggling to solve this past paper question:

> Cars arrive at a particular junction at a rate of 1.5 per minute. A
>   little old lady takes 20 seconds to cross the road at this junction
>   and sets out as soon as one car passes. What is the probability that
>   she gets across the road before the next car arrives?

The answer is 0.607, any idea how they got to that answer?

Comment: Have you heard of Poisson processes?

Comment: Sorry, I should of mentioned what I have tried, I did try solving this with the poisson distribution, maybe I went wrong in my arithmetic

Comment: A Poisson process would mean that the gaps between cars would be exponentially distributed

Comment: What's the chance that no car arrives in the next one-third of a minute?

Comment: They used a Poison model, since their number is about $e^{-0.5}$.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with the Poisson distribution so that someone can check your arithmetic?